# what is the best way to close a ByteArrayOutputStream?

Tags: java, memory, stream, heap-memory, bytearrayoutputstream

I need to optimize a application that uses too much heap memory.
I'm having problem in close a ByteArrayOutputStream variable after using the same. I've tried to do using close() but it does not work. this is the code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream zipOutTempStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
//arquivo.getZipStream() has the XML received by FTP.
//STreamEtils is the function who transfers the XML to zipOutTempStream
StreamUtils.copiarStream(arquivo.getZipStream(), zipOutTempStream);

            //Creating a new XML to write over this.
            File arquivo1 = new File("C:/XML.xml");
            if (arquivo1.exists()) {
                System.out.println("ele existe");
            } else {
                if (arquivo1.createNewFile()) {
                    System.out.println("arquivo criado");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("arquivo não criado");
                }
            }

            FileOutputStream arquivo2 = new FileOutputStream(arquivo1);
            //Copy the unziped XML to the new xml created.
            StreamUtils.copiarStream(StreamUtils                .uncompressXmlFromZipStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(zipOutTempStream.toByteArray())), arquivo2);
            arquivo.setZipStream(null);
            arquivo.setXmlStream(null)      
return arquivo;
```

Comment: how does it not work? Do you get an error?

Comment: A `ByteArrayOutputStream` writes data to a byte array.  After closing the `ByteArrayOutputStream` the byte array is accessible with the `toByteArray` method.  Simply closing the `ByteArrayOutputStream` will not make the byte array eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: i works, but the problem is that i have a XML of 80MB and after i save in C: , i'd like to free the heap memory used.

Comment: That is the job of the garbage collector.  Make sure that you do not have extra references to the `ByteArrayOutputStream` hanging around.

Answer (score 12):

You cannot close a ByteArrayOutputStream, since it's [close()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#close%28%29) method is documented as

> *Closing a ByteArrayOutputStream has no effect. The methods in this
>   class can be called after the stream has been closed without
>   generating an IOException.*

This output stream is backed by an array; it is **NOT** a buffered stream. If you feel it is using too much memory, you should output bytes directly to some endpoint, such as a file or a socket, using an appropriate OutputStream.

Comment: the problem is that i should to unzip the file received by FTP and just to get the XML that is in. How can i do that, using what?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are carelessly using too much memory. `close()` has nothing to do with it. In fact there is no need for closing `ByteArrayOutputStream`. Here you are copying the ZIP file into wrapped `byte[]` array:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream zipOutTempStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
StreamUtils.copiarStream(arquivo.getZipStream(), zipOutTempStream);
```

and few lines later you convert the `byte[]` array back to `InputStream`:

```
StreamUtils.copiarStream(StreamUtils.uncompressXmlFromZipStream(
  new ByteArrayInputStream(zipOutTempStream.toByteArray())
), arquivo2);
```

Seems like this generated `byte[]` array is pretty huge (confirm with logging). Instead of storing the whole ZIP file in memory (in `byte[]`) store in a temporary file and read it back.